# How to Merge two or more multidimensional arrays into single multidimensional array using Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to merge my four 3D arrays into single 3D array in java,

```
Object[][][] obj1,obj2,obj3,obj4;
obj1 = new Object[7][8][7];
obj2 = new Object[7][8][7];
obj3 = new Object[7][8][7];
obj4 = new Object[7][8][7];
```

As above, i need one

```
Object[][][] total = Object[28][32][28];
// total = obj1+obj2+obj3+obj4;
```

Comment: As you can imagine a 3D view, your total array it twice too big, if you put all your 4 arrays in the same plan, the height will be same, just width of both side *2

Answer (score 2):

`Stream` the arrays, collect the stream to a `List` and then convert to an array. Something like,

```
Object[][][] total = Stream.of(obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4)
        .collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new Object[0][0][0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that I missed flattening of stream before passing it to collect.  Adding "flatMap" resolved the issue.

```
data1 = Stream.of(data1, data2).flatMap (a -> Arrays.stream(a)).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new String [0][0]);
```